# How to set PathIcon from code behind?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

How would I write the following XAML in code behind?  I'm having a problem understanding the PathIcon Data part of it.

```
<AppBarToggleButton Label="PathIcon" Click="AppBarButton_Click">
    <AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
        <PathIcon Data="F1 M 20,20L 24,10L 24,24L 5,24"/>
    </AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
</AppBarToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try,

```
this.appBarButton.Icon = new PathIcon(){ Data = PathMarkupToGeometry(Your xaml data string)};
```

in this case: xaml data string is `F1 M 20,20L 24,10L 24,24L 5,24`

```
Geometry PathMarkupToGeometry(string pathMarkup)
{
        string xaml =
        "<Path " +
        "xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>" +
        "<Path.Data>" + pathMarkup + "</Path.Data></Path>";
        var path = XamlReader.Load(xaml) as Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path;
        // Detach the PathGeometry from the Path
        Geometry geometry = path.Data;
        path.Data = null;
        return geometry;
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 4):

In Resource Dictionary (xaml):

```
   <x:String x:Key="LargePathIcon">M3 20V3H20V20H3ZM19 4H4V19H19V4Z</x:String>
```

In .cs

```
var icon = new PathIcon();
icon.Data = (Geometry) XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(Geometry), (string) App.Current.Resources["LargePathIcon"]);
```

Comment: I've been looking around for solutions to convert SVG to Geometry for quite some time now. Your answer saved my day! I never realized there's this helper class existed.